# Azure B2C encrypting SAML Response

Tags: saml, azure-ad-b2c

I have a SP requiring the SAML response to be encrypted.  Looking at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers#1-set-up-certificates), it shows an optional key, but then never shows how to use it.  How do I encrypt the SAML response using the SP public key so they can decrypt it with their private key.  I have a public metadata endpoint from the SP which does have the encrypt section in it with a key.  However I'm missing something because the response isn't being encrypted.

Comment: The documents you are referring are the right one and the metadata URL is needs to be configured in the manifest - otherwise "Azure AD B2C will not validate the SAML request signature, nor encrypt the SAML response" according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers#replyurlswithtype-optional)

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I do have the manifest configured according to that document.

Comment: For configuring Azure AD SAML token encryption please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/howto-saml-token-encryption)

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I think that document is for Azure AD.  I am working on Azure B2C Custom Policies.  I don't have a token configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get this to work with Microsoft's help.  Here is what we had to do:

1. Make sure the SP Metadata endpoint was public and had an KeyDescriptor with use="encryption" in it.
2. Add the SamlAssertionDecryptionKey to the CryptographicKeys section of the SAMLIssuer.  We set this to the same key as the AssertionSigning.  They said it isn't actually used but required right now.
3. Add true to the Metadata in the relyingparty section.

Once this was configured, our custom policy encrypted the outgoing SAML Assertion as required by the SP we were working with.

Documentation is being updated by Microsoft.